# Passing multiple JSON objects as a single JSON objects Rails to AngularJS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have a function that has multiple objects. I would like to pass these objects as one JSON object from my rails app to my angularjs app

```
@states = State.all
@nationalities = Nationality.all

    @states_nationalities = {
      states: @states,
      nationalities: @nationalities
    }
```

I thought i could do this but I am getting an error. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hash.to_json**

```
@states_nationalities.to_json
```

or for rendering

```
render :json  @states_nationalities
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@states_nationalities = {
  states: @states,
  nationalities: @nationalities
}
```

The above snippet when render as JSON should output this structure (barring that there isn't data returned from the AR calls).

```
{
  "states": [{}, {}, {}],
  "nationalities": [{}, {}, {}]
}
```

Both keys point to an array of objects that are your states and nationalities in your app.

What's the goal for the JSON structure to look like/what's the error you're getting?